# Difference between expression lambda and statement lambda

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, anonymous-function

Is there a difference between expression lambda and statement lambda?

If so, what is the difference?

Found this question in the below link but could not understand the answer 
What is Expression Lambda?

[C# interview Questions](http://csharpinterviewfaq.blogspot.in/2010/01/linq.html)

The answer mentioned in that link is this
**A lambda expression with an expression on the right side is called an expression lambda.**

Per my understanding always the expression is in the right hand side only. That is why I am asking this question. Is there anything I am unaware of?

Comment: Sources for where you encountered both terms would help us explain the difference, if any.

Comment: Do you mean the `Expression.Lambda` method call?

Comment: Added the source from where i got confused.

Comment: Doesn't the source actually show you the difference?

Comment: @millimoose: I could not understand that. It just says A lambda expression with an expression on the right side is called an expression lambda.

Comment: @ckv It also shows several examples. It also describes a *statement lambda* which is the "opposite". With several examples. (Although the blog sorely needs a code display plugin. And generally looks kind of crappy.)

Comment: The question is fun. My personal suggestion is, to understand what is an *expression* and what is a *lambda expression*, then you'll have no problem.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is indeed confusing jargon; we couldn't come up with anything better.

A *lambda expression* is the catch-all term for any of these:

```
x => M(x)
(x, y) => M(x, y)
(int x, int y) => M(x, y)
x => { return M(x); }
(x, y) => { return M(x, y); }
(int x, int y) => { return M(x, y); }
```

The first three are *expression lambdas* because the right hand side of the lambda operator is an expression. The last three are *statement lambdas* because the right hand side of the lambda operator is a *block*.

This also illustrates that there are three possible syntaxes for the left side: either a single parameter name, or a parenthesized list of untyped parameters, or a parenthesized list of typed parameters.

Comment: Is that all the difference? a statement and statements within blocks.

Comment: @ckv When compiled into a `Func<T>`, not really.  When compiled into an `Expression<Func<T>>`, yes.  For example, some query providers parsing expressions can't handle statement lambdas, or must have statement lambdas in a certain context, etc.  In short, the expression tree created is radically different, and whoever is "using" it may care a lot about those details.  For just a plain `Func<T>`, the underlying code run when you invoke it is (hopefully) an abstraction you don't need to worry about.

Comment: @ckv: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @Eric I think i got it. I just wanted to know the difference in the 2 usage of the 2 terms: Expression Lambda and Lambda Expression.

Comment: @ckv It would be better if they had been called "Lambda Expression" (i.e. the whole), and "Expression Lambda Expression" (i.e. the part). As I said before, you should consider better learning material than a terribly formatted anonymous blog.

Comment: @millimoose Sure i understand that. I dont have a book ready with me to refer so had to browse to find the answer.

Comment: @Servy Except you can't convert a statement lambda into an `Expression`. You *can* create an `Expression` that represents a statement (since .Net 4.0), but you have to use the expression trees API manually for that.

Comment: @svick: I think some of statement lambdas can actually be rewritten as an expression.

Comment: How do you compete with a man that responds about C# saying "...we couldn't come up with anything better."?

Comment: @C.Lang: Simple, don't compete; to cooperate. I think to serve people as your will is more constructive.

Answer (score 19):

Yes there is - or I should probably say that one defines the other.

A **lambda expression** allows you to assign simple anonymous functions.

An **expression lambda** *is a* type of lambda that has an expression to the right of the lambda operator.

The other type of lambda expression is a **statement lambda** because it contains a statement block `{...}` to the right side of the expression.

- Expression lambda takes the form: `number => (number % 2 == 0)`
- Statement lambda takes the form:  `number => { return number > 5 }`

Comment: @millimoose, my English is probably failing me again. The article mentioned by the questioner differentiates expression lambdas (versus statement lambdas) as lambdas whose bodies only consist in a single expression. IIRC "expression" lambdas can be assigned to `Expression<Func<T>>` but "statement" lambdas cannot.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Correct.  And statement lambdas and expression lambdas are the two different types of lambda expressions.  A lambda is either wrapping a statement or an expression.  The resulting lambda is itself an expression (regardless of which of the two it is wrapping).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for answering even though I was being overly snippy there. "Whose bodies consist of" is a better phrasing, I was confused by "returns an expression" since I think of a lambda as returning the result of whatever the body is.

Comment: @millimoose, that's why I actually said `evaluates an expression`, but I guess that was even more confusing ;)

Answer (score 10):

A *lambda expression* is a syntax that allows you to create a function without name directly inside your code, as an expression.

There are two kinds of lambda expressions, depending on their body:

- *expression lambdas*, whose body is just an expression, e.g. `(i, j) => i + j`
- *statement lambdas*, whose body is a full statement, e.g.. `(i, j) => { return i + j; }`

Answer (score 1):

lampda expression is an anonymous function that the compiler can either turn into a `Func<T>` or an `Expression<Func<T>>` (inferred by compiler depending on usage).

It is not entirely clear what you mean by "expression lamdba", but if you have heard the phrase in a podcast/webcast or something it is probably either referring to a lambda expression. Or it could be the property [Expression.Lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda.aspx), which you use to obtain a lambda from an Expression instance.