# Is there a difference between C# lambda functions with brackets vs no brackets?

Tags: c#

These two lines in C# seem to do the same thing:

```
int idIndex = row.attributeNames.FindIndex(i => i.ToString() == "searchTerm");
int idIndex = row.attributeNames.FindIndex((object i) => { return i.ToString() == "searchTerm"; });
```

Are these two lines executed differently at all?

It seems not, but I remember seeing somewhere that there are different ways of writing lambdas in C# that are executed slightly differently.

Comment: If in first case `i` is `object` then there're the same. First one is a shorthand of the second. Both are `Func<object, bool>` or it's the same as `Predicate<object>`. And both are delegates with signature `bool(object i)`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240642/difference-between-lambda-expression-and-expression-lambda (not quite the same question, but still relevant)